# React-Native how to show different API by same id in Flatlist

Tags: react-native

i have two different API and i want show two API in one Flatlist this is worked (look the picture). i show it using filter by id API (if API have same id will show). My question is how to remove/hide/dont show null value flatlist (look the picture)?
Im using API from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

[picture my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvkyq.png)

```
  const {user, post} = useSelector(state => state.reducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const getData = [...user, ...post];

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProfile());
    dispatch(getPost());
  }, []);


  const tailwind = useTailwind();

const renderPost = ({item}) => {
    const renUsr = user.filter(renUsr => renUsr.id === item.userId);
    return (
      renUsr.id !== item.userId ? (
        <View style={tailwind('pb-4')}>
          <View style={tailwind('px-4 py-4 bg-gray-200 mx-6 rounded-[20px]')}>
            <View style={tailwind('flex flex-row')}>
              <Image style={tailwind('rounded bg-black w-8 h-8')} />
              {renUsr.map(posting => (
                <Text
                  key={posting.id}
                  style={tailwind('pl-2 font-semibold py-2')}>
                  {posting.name}
                </Text>
              ))}
            </View>
            <View style={tailwind('mt-2')}>
              <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.touchHighlight}
                onPress={navigation}>
                <View style={tailwind('bg-gray-200 p-1')}>
                  <Text key={item.id}>{item.body}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      ) : (
        null
      ) 
    );
  };

  return (
      <FlatList
        data={getData}
        renderItem={renderPost}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet?

Comment: yes, im forgot to share code, wait i will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user.filter(renUsr => renUsr.id === item.userId);
```

Instead of using the filter here, just filter the list passed to the flatlist so you it will be looped only once and you don't to filter for every single item